# How to avoid code duplication in observer mutation

Tags: javascript

There is the following structure (the example itself is non-working, it is here to understand the structure): [sandbox](https://jsfiddle.net/suqcxLg1/)

And in this structure some actions are repeated. How to avoid JS code duplication? For example in self-invoking functions.

```js
// ObserverAddRule

function ObserverAddRule() {
  const target1 = document.querySelector('#form_edit_rule .sc')
  const target2 = document.querySelector('#form_edit_rule .sc1')

  const config = {
    childList: true
  }

  const callback = function (mutationsList, observer) {
    for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
      if (mutation.type === 'childList') {

        (function(){
        
          let scFrstItem = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.sc .acrList .frstItem .mySelect')).slice(-1) 
          let scScndItem = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.sc .acrList .scndItem.scnd-title .mySelect')).slice(-1) 
          
          let scElements = scFrstItem.concat(scScndItem)

          initChoices(false, '', false, false, scElements) 
          delegateEventChoices() // <here you need to pass .sc>
          
        })();

        (function(){
        
          let sc1FrstItem = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.sc1 .acrList .frstItem .mySelect')).slice(-1) 
          let sc1ScndItem = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.sc1 .acrList .scndItem.scnd-title .mySelect')).slice(-1) 
          
          let sc1Elements = sc1FrstItem.concat(sc1ScndItem)

          initChoices(false, '', false, false, sc1Elements)
          delegateEventChoices() // <here you need to pass .sc1>

        })();

      }
    }
  }

  const observer = new MutationObserver(callback)

  observer.observe(target1, config)
  observer.observe(target2, config)
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="form_edit_rule" method="post">
  <div class="sc">
    <div class="acrList">
      <div class="frstItem">
        <p class="mySelect">ТЕКСТ</p>
      </div>
      <div class="scndItem scnd-title">
        <p class="mySelect">ТЕКСТ</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div class="sc1">
    <div class="acrList">
      <div class="frstItem">
        <p class="mySelect">ТЕКСТ</p>
      </div>
      <div class="scndItem scnd-title">
        <p class="mySelect">ТЕКСТ</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I really do not want to hang the mutation of the observer on their common parent - to redo a lot. But if this is the only method, then write about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way to avoid duplication is by using parameters.

Self-invoked function is intended to run on-spot, only once, it's not intended to repeat.

So, if you have repeating functionality, then separate function(s) and/or use  parameters for changeable data.

Two possible solutions:

1. Pass parameter to self-invokable function

https://jsfiddle.net/uxcva6wy/1/

```
const callback = function (mutationsList, observer) {
  for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {

      (function(namespaces){
        for(let namespace in namespaces) {
          let scFrstItem = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(namespace + ' .acrList .frstItem .mySelect')).slice(-1) 
          let scScndItem = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(namespace + ' .acrList .scndItem.scnd-title .mySelect')).slice(-1) 

          let scElements = scFrstItem.concat(scScndItem)

          initChoices(false, '', false, false, scElements) 
          delegateEventChoices() // <here you need to pass .sc>
        }
      })(['.sc', '.sc1']);
    }
  }
}
```

2. Create separate, callable function

https://jsfiddle.net/uxcva6wy/2/

```
const doSomething = function(namespace){
    let scFrstItem = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(namespace + ' .acrList .frstItem .mySelect')).slice(-1) 
    let scScndItem = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(namespace + ' .acrList .scndItem.scnd-title .mySelect')).slice(-1) 

    let scElements = scFrstItem.concat(scScndItem)

    initChoices(false, '', false, false, scElements) 
    delegateEventChoices() // <here you need to pass .sc>
};

const callback = function (mutationsList, observer) {
  for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
      doSomething('.sc');
      doSomething('.sc1');
    }
  }
}
```

If you need more specific answer, please post more specific snippet.

Comment: I do not know why I created this ticket. Apparently, it was too late, and my brain was tired. This morning I tried to do as I usually do, and it worked, but you have a very interesting implementation approach.

SandBox: https://jsfiddle.net/o0sypfqm/